# mypy with numbers.Number

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I was hoping to use mypy's static duck typing facility to write a function that can process a sequence of number-like objects, where "number-like" is defined by numbers.Number:

```py
from numbers import Number
from typing import Sequence

def something_numerical(xs: Sequence[Number]) -> Number:
  ...

print(something_numerical([1., 2., 3.]))
```

However, when I call this code with a list of floats or ints, I get a mypy error:

```bash
$ print(multiply([1., 2., 3.]))
foo/foo.py:9: error: List item 0 has incompatible type "float"; expected "Number"
foo/foo.py:9: error: List item 1 has incompatible type "float"; expected "Number"
foo/foo.py:9: error: List item 2 has incompatible type "float"; expected "Number"
```

I realize that the `float` type is not a subclass of `numbers.Number`. However, the numbers module provides a set of abstract base classes that are intended to be used to check whether an object has the requisite methods to do numerical operations. How might I rewrite this code so that (1) it can still process ints, floats, fractios.Fraction, and so on, and (2) so that it passes type checking by mypy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was stated in @bzu answer, but I'd like to add some explanation to it.

First thing to note: `issubclass(int, Number)` and `issubclass(float, Number)` both evaluate to True. This is very surprising type-checking behavior, but it was standardized in [PEP484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower):

> Rather than requiring that users write import numbers and then use `numbers.Float` etc., this PEP proposes a straightforward shortcut that is almost as effective: when an argument is annotated as having type `float`, an argument of type `int` is acceptable; similar, for an argument annotated as having type `complex`, arguments of type `float` or `int` are acceptable. This does not handle classes implementing the corresponding ABCs or the `fractions.Fraction` class, but we believe those use cases are exceedingly rare.

So to support built-in numbers you can use just `int`, `float` or `complex`. To handle other ABC's you should use appropriate `numbers` member. I don't know why `float` was not made compatible with `numbers.Number`.

For almost all cases you can use a type alias (`TypeAlias` was backported with `typing_extensions` module for python<3.10):

```py
from fractions import Fraction
from numbers import Number
from typing import TypeAlias


AnyNumber: TypeAlias = Number | float

def f(x: AnyNumber) -> bool:
    return x == 0


f(1)
f(1.0)
f(Fraction(1, 3))
```

This typechecks. One incompatible class I'm aware of is `decimal.Decimal`: it is not compatible (it would be expected, if `Number` were made compatible with `float`, because `Decimal` is not and `Decimal(1) / 2` fails - but it is not the case, as we'll see later).

If your function uses `AnyNumber` and `int` together, everything dies:

```py
def f(x: AnyNumber) -> float:
    return x / 2 + 1  # E: Unsupported operand types for / ("Number" and "int")
```

Although you can, for example, do `Fraction(1,2) / 2`, `Number` does not guarantee int or float compatibility. You can use `numbers.Real` or `numbers.Complex` instead - they are compatible with `float`:

```py
AnyReal: TypeAlias = Real | float
```

This allows `x / 2 + 1` and remains incompatible with `decimal.Decimal`, but now it is intended behavior.

You can use [this playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=de9b5953dde921438210d5362182ceb6) to investigate the topic further. Also having look at [`numbers` in typeshed](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/typeshed/stdlib/numbers.pyi) may help.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @SUTerliakov is informative and accurate; however, while working on this problem I came across another way of solving the problem that I will post here for others who encounter this. I simply defined my own "Number" protocol from scratch:

```py
from typing import Protocol

class Number(Protocol):
    def __abs__(self) -> 'Number':
        ...
    def __mul__(self, Number) -> 'Number':
        ...
    def __add__(self, Number) -> 'Number':
        ...
    def __lt__(self, Number) -> bool:
        ...
    def __gt__(self, Number) -> bool:
        ...
    def __truediv__(self, Number) -> 'Number':
        ...
    def __rtruediv__(self, Number) -> 'Number':
        ...
```

Here the choice to include `__mul__`, `__abs__`, `__truediv__` and so on were based on the operations I needed to perform inside my function, rather than based on any abstract notion of what a number ought or ought not to be.

It seems that the "number" concept in python is quite complicated and hard to fit all cases, so it really might make logical sense to define a per-project protocol like this.

Comment: Nice approach, but please edit arguments to be `__other: <something>` instead of implicit `Number: Any`. (`<something>` could be a type var, but not `Number` itself, otherwise even `int` is incompatible)

Comment: You have `def __mul__(self, Number) -> 'Number'`. This is a function with two arguments: `self` and `Number`, both untyped, and `mypy` interprets it as `def __mul__(self, Number: Any) -> Number`. You probably want to have variable `__other` (double underscore in protocol -> name does not matter) with some type. This type cannot be `Number`, because `def __mul__(self, __other: Number) -> Number` is not compatible with `int` (see definition [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/typeshed/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L243=))

Answer (score 1):

It seems using Union will be the way to go:

```
from numbers import Number
from typing import Sequence, Union
from fractions import Fraction


def something_numerical(xs: Sequence[Union[Number, float]]) -> Union[Number, float]:
    return sum(xs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(something_numerical([1.2, 2, Fraction(1, 2)]))
```

Comment: This [fails](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=e67e682dcacdc95d6173a94cc593b2ce), replace `sum` with something else?